# How can I send emails with Mail.app as text/markdown explicitly?

Tags: mail.app, email, defaults, plugins, markdown

I write all my emails in plain text, not rich text or HTML, but I do use [punctuation markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language) as has been popularized by Markdown and others (which were inspired by prior customs in plain-text email). There’s [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7763) 7763 now, which registers the `text/markdown` media type with mandatory `charset` and optional [`variant`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7764) parameters.
Can I change Apple Mail to always send a respective MIME header?

```
Content-Type: text/markdown; charset=UTF-8; variant=pandoc; extensions=-raw_html
```

I hope for some `defaults write` magic since there doesn’t seem to be a respective plugin available ([yet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/issues/80)). Something like this:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders \
  '{"Content-Type: text/markdown; charset=UTF-8; variant=pandoc; extensions=-raw_html"; }'
```

Comment: Are you aware of any mail client which does this already?  Or any mail client which renders rich text when it receives a message with such a header?

Comment: @TomGewecke Not really. [MailMate](https://blog.freron.com/category/feature/) and [Groups.io](http://groups.io) support `Content-Type: text/plain; markup=markdown"`, though, which would need the same kind of hackery in Mail.app. I’ve filed a [feature request to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html) and will do so for Thunderbird.

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/questions/1361551/using-text-markdown-in-emails for why this, unfortunately, might not be such a great idea after all.

Answer (score 2):

Would [Brett Terpstra’s Markdown Service Tools](http://brettterpstra.com/2013/10/24/markdown-service-tools-update-for-mavericks/) provide what you need? Here's [a nice blog-post](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/use-markdown-anywhere-on-a-mac-with-markdown-service-tools--cms-21406) explaining how to it up and running, also en Mail.

Comment: No, not at all. These macros are helful for writing and converting Markdown, but do nothing to alter the format Mail is using.

Comment: My bad. Guess I misunderstood your question.